# Can i overclock an Intel Core i3 processor?

Tags: cpu, overclocking, dell-optiplex, hardware-acceleration

I have a Dell Optiplex 3020 with this exact CPU,I want to overclock it to enhance crypto mining and downloading files. Before I go all in and do it, I'm making sure on this site.

Comment: Downloading won't go faster after overclocking (cpu is basically never the bottleneck); and mining crypto is pointless and bad for the environment https://web3isgoinggreat.com/ GPUs are better for mining than CPUs (in almost all cases). Unless your power is free and you have lots of money and experience you are unlikely to make a profit. Don't waste your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hope you know that CPU crypto mining isn’t profitable, essentially, with a under unoverclockable powered CPU

Comment: What exact CPU? i3 is a range of processors, not a specific model. Specific models may be over clockable, and if you tell us the actual specific model we might be able to get you this information. Note that Intel's own product information charts, all available online, also list the features of each model.

Answer (score 4):

The ability and ways to overclock depends on a good many things - chipset, processor and so on. Chances are that a work oriented PC with a lower end processor is *unlikely* to have overclocking/enthusiast centric features.

That said overclocking is not magic. It can squeeze maybe the last bit of performance from a decent chip but it isn't going to get massive performance boosts.

> I want to overclock it to enhance crypto mining and downloading files.

I'm tempted to go on a rant about the evils of crypto *but* cryptocurrency mining is mostly done on GPUs and ASICs, and overclocking your PC wouldn't improve your performance much. You'd essentially be shortening your PC's life and using more power for not much benefit

I don't think even an older core i3 with *good* or even *decent* storage would bottleneck on downloads. Your storage might be a bottleneck (and with a computer of that age - it probably has a hard drive and a cheap SSD would result in fairly substantial performance gains. I used to run a *laptop* chip with a similar age of processor (4th generation intel) for downloads via bitorrent and file services and it was fine.

In short, you probably *can't* and there's no real advantage to

Comment: Dogs always agree with me. And I agree with them. Woof

Comment: Dogs are generally agreeable creatures :D